# React Native : Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: react-native, components, state

**iOS** `Error:  Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

**Android** `Error: Requested Keys of a value is not an object`

I'm trying to pass an object from a different file as a prop to a component from my screen component for it to load the data. I successfully did one component and pass in the data object as a prop but when I add another component to do the same it doesn't work and gives two different errors on both devices. The Android shows that error is on the StoriesBar.js file on line 24 which is where I declare the `.cloneWithRows` to a state, but the iOS doesn't show where the error is.

**Feed.js**

```
...
import { Stories, Posts } from '../data';
export default class Feed extends Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    <StoriesBar
                        stories={Stories.data} <-- This does not work...
                    />
                    <PostCard
                        posts={Posts.data} <-- This works
                    />
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

**StoriesBar.js**

```
...
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });

export default class StoriesBar extends Component {
    ...
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            stories: ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.stories), <-- Line that is causing the crash
        };
    }
}
```

**PostCard.js**

```
...
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });

export default class PostCard extends Component {
    ...
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            posts: ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.posts), <-- This works...
        };
    }
}
```

However, when I include the file StoriesBar.js replace the `this.props.stories` with `Stories.data` directly it works. Both the object files are formated the exact same...

UPDATE: After logging every couple steps i found out that it does get through to the prop and I can see the array in the console log but for some reason the component reloads and then it becomes undefined. Only when I hard code a prop like `test={'test}` and log that does it stay the same.

[Image to the console log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BTsx.png)

Comment: can you attach your `data` file in this question?

Comment: @Harlan I don't think the problem is the data file because it works when I use it directly inside the StoriesBar.js file but not through the prop. But when I do the exact same with the PostCard.js it works perfectly fine both ways.

Comment: Have you try `console.log()` to log `Stories` and `Posts`

Comment: @Harlan It comes out as undefined? Why is it coming out as undefined??? When I do `this.state = { stories: ds.cloneWithRows(Stories.data) }` with the `Stories` being imported within the file it work, but not through a prop?? I tried other props and logged it and it worked

Comment: @Harlan I added an update to the question